# Sorting groups of values according to total value

Tags: java, sorting

I'm writing an app for evaluating points and ranks of a competition and I have this specific problem:

I have groups of teams, each consists of 4 competitors. Each member of team has some penalty points which is then summed up for a whole team. For example like this:

```
Team1    name,     discipline1, discipline2, discipline3, total, RANK
first    xxxxxxxx, 10         , 20         , 30         , 60   , 2
second   xxxxxxxx, 10         , 20         , 30         , 60   , 2
third    xxxxxxxx, 10         , 20         , 30         , 60   , 2
fourth   xxxxxxxx, 10         , 20         , 30         , 60   , 2
total              40         , 80         , 120        , 240

Team2    name,     discipline1, discipline2, discipline3, total, RANK
first    xxxxxxxx, 10         , 10         , 30         , 50   , 1
second   xxxxxxxx, 10         , 10         , 30         , 50   , 1
third    xxxxxxxx, 10         , 10         , 30         , 50   , 1
fourth   xxxxxxxx, 10         , 10         , 30         , 50   , 1
total              40         , 40         , 120        , 200
```

and so on...

I need to sort these groups of teams according to the total penalty points in total/total cell. Any hints how to effectively solve this? This is my first app in java so I will appreciate any help.

Comment: implement Comparable interface into your class and overwrite compareTo() method

Comment: @JordiCastilla: I was thinking about storing these groups of data into double-dimension arrays and sort them according to total values.. But I dont know if it's good approach to solve this..

Comment: @OnderHorka check my answer, you must work a bit on it, but I think is the correct approach to your needs

Answer (score 0):

You should use List to store Team class instances, so you can sort them easily. Look for examples with Comparator and Comparable interfaces. Team class will contain teamMembers, that store TeamMember class instance with penalties, and TeamMember should have getter method for penalties sum. This method will be called from team instance, to account team penalties sum. So in your comparison you will be able to call team method, that returns sum of team members penalties.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I don't know if teams or competitors will have more than the example data, and this is one of your first `Java` apps I would recommend approach this problem usin simple objects to start with [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

Create two classes: `Team` and `Competitor`.

- `Team` class must have a `List<Competitor>`, name, and a method to calculate the penalty:

**Team.java**

```
public class Team { 
    private String name; 

    private List<Competitor> competitors;

    // create getters and setters for name and competitors....

    // constructor:
    public Team(String name) {
         this.name = name;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        int totalScore;

        // sum all scores of the team using Competitor.getScore()
        for (Competitor c : competitors) {
            totalScore += c.getScore();
        }

        return totalScore;
    }
}
```

- `Competitor` class must have a `List<Integer>`, name, surname and a method to calculate the score of the entity:

**Competitor.java**

```
public class Competitor { 
    private String name; 
    private String surname; 

    // you can also create a Discipline class... but 
    // I think is not mandatory in this case
    private List<Integer> punctuations;  // store the punctuations

    // create getters and setters for name, surname and punctuations

    public int getScore() {
        int totalScore = 0;

        // sum all scores of the competitor
        for (Integer punctuation : punctuations) {
            totalScore += punctuation;
        }

        return totalScore;
    }
}
```

Then you just have to process it in your `Main` depending of your number of teams and competitions:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      // create teams
      Team t1 = new Team("T1");
      List<Competitors> t1Competitors = new ArrayList<>();

      // create competitors
      Competitor c1 = new Competitor("John", "Doe");

      // fill competitors info
      List<Integer> c1Punctuation = new ArrayList<>();
      c1Punctuation.add("10");
      c1Punctuation.add("20");
      c1Punctuation.add("30");

      c1.setPunctuation(c1Punctuation);

      // put competitors into teams
      t1Competitors.add(c1);
      t1.setCompetitors(t1Competitors);

      // get team punctuations
      int t1Score = t1.getScore();

      // repeat and compare t1Score and t2Score and so on... 

}
```

Comment: let me know if you have some doubt implementing it :)

Answer (score 0):

I have written a program check this out. It sorts the teams based on the total penalty points.

class Player

```
class Player{

    String name;
    Integer d1;
    Integer d2;
    Integer d3;
    Integer d4;
    Integer total;
    Integer Rank;

 //Getters Setters
```

class Team

```
public class Team {

    ArrayList<Player> player;
    Integer teamTotal;

    public ArrayList<Player> getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    public void setPlayer(ArrayList<Player> player) {
        this.player = player;
    }

    public Integer getTeamTotal() {
        return teamTotal;
    }

    public void setTeamTotal(ArrayList<Player> player) {
        int tmpTeamTotal=0;
        for (Player p : player) {
            tmpTeamTotal += p.getTotal();
        }
        System.out.println(tmpTeamTotal);
        teamTotal=tmpTeamTotal;
    }

    public static Comparator<Team> totalComparator = new Comparator<Team>() {
        public int compare(Team tOne, Team tTwo) {
            return (tOne.getTeamTotal() - tTwo.getTeamTotal());
        }
    };

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.valueOf(this.getTeamTotal());

    }
}
```

Client class

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Player pOne = new Player();
        pOne.setD1(10);
        pOne.setD2(20);
        pOne.setD3(30);
        pOne.setD4(60);
        pOne.setRank(2);
        pOne.setName("ABD");
        pOne.setTotal(60);

        Player pTwo=new Player();
        pTwo.setD1(20);
        pTwo.setD2(20);
        pTwo.setD3(40);
        pTwo.setD4(70);
        pTwo.setRank(2);
        pTwo.setName("SPC");
        pTwo.setTotal(60);

        ArrayList<Player> playerListOne = new ArrayList<Player>();
        playerListOne.add(pOne);
        playerListOne.add(pTwo);

        Player pTOne = new Player();
        pTOne.setD1(10);
        pTOne.setD2(70);
        pTOne.setD3(30);
        pTOne.setD4(90);
        pTOne.setRank(2);
        pTOne.setName("ABD");
        pTOne.setTotal(60);

        Player pTTwo=new Player();
        pTTwo.setD1(20);
        pTTwo.setD2(20);
        pTTwo.setD3(40);
        pTTwo.setD4(60);
        pTTwo.setRank(2);
        pTTwo.setName("SPC");
        pTTwo.setTotal(80);
        ArrayList<Player> playerListTwo = new ArrayList<Player>();
        playerListTwo.add(pTOne);
        playerListTwo.add(pTTwo);

        Team one=new Team();
        one.setPlayer(playerListOne);
        one.setTeamTotal(playerListOne);

        Team two=new Team();
        two.setPlayer(playerListTwo);
        two.setTeamTotal(playerListTwo);

        ArrayList<Team> team=new ArrayList<Team>();
        team.add(one);
        team.add(two);

        Collections.sort(team, Team.totalComparator);
        System.out.println(team);


    }

}
```

As per the data input First team total penalty point:120
Second team total penalty point: 140
Program output: [120, 140]